# Rails send mail to a user every day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, actionmailer

I'm trying to use whenever gem (or maybe there's a better solution ?)
I've been trying to make this work, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Here is my schedule.rb :

```
every :day, :at => '12pm' do # Use any day of the week or :weekend, :weekday
  runner "UserMailer.daily_mail"
end
```

My UserMailer :

```
def daily_mail(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Mail journalier"
end
```

And in my user.rb :

```
  def send_daily_mail
    UserMailer.daily_mail(self).deliver
  end
```

The thing is, I already have mail activation in my project, which is working (I can test it in heroku). The app sends a mail on creation of an account, so in UserController, there is :

```
    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        @user.send_activation_email
        flash[:info] = "Veuillez contrôler votre boîte mail pour activer votre compte."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
```

But here, it sends an email after an action. But If I want the mail to be sent with whenever, what is left to do to make it work, and how can I test it since I'm not in production (and I think whenever doesn't work with heroku) ?

The endgame would be to have a checkbox in the user preferences, and he would be able to check daily, weekly or monthly updates, and the mails would be sent accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: Your script ` runner "UserMailer.daily_mail"` isn't passing a user to the `daily_mail` action.  Can you explain what your requirements are for who gets emailed, and when?

Comment: My goal is to add a field into User table, a simple boolean if he wants to receive a daily mail or not. I want the task to send a mail to every user that activated this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a `rake` task something like:

```
desc "Send email to users"

task :email_sender => :environment do |_, args|
  User.find_each do |user|
    UserMailer.daily_mail(user).deliver if <YOUR_LOGIC_TO_CHECK_IF_YOU_NEED_TO_SEND_EMAIL>
  end
end
```

In `config/schedule.rb`:

```
every :day, :at => '12pm' do
  rake "email_sender"
end
```

Comment: I don't need to use user.rb then ? For checkboxes, I thought about adding field in User table, and check if user.daily is true or something. Would that work ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to add a new column to the table for storing frequency of the required email. It will get used while calculating if you need to send email to user in particular rake execution or not.

Comment: I'll do this and let you know then. How can I test if this function work since whenever gem doesn't work in heroku ?

Comment: I've added the checkboxes and they are working flawlessly. Now I'd like to test if the rake task works with the schedule.rb but I don't know how

Comment: Thats cool @Komarzer. Lets post new question for this so that it can have individual answer, which will help others too